# Automator quarantine Gatekeeper workaround?

Tags: applescript, automator, gatekeeper

I am using my Developer certificate to sign Automator Apps via the Export dialogue, however when distributing these apps (outside the Mac App store) via email, Gatekeeper still flags my apps as a from an unknown developer. I gather from the Apple Developer forums that non-App store apps are tagged with a quarantine of some sort.

I am hoping to see if someone else has encountered a similar issue and found a workaround. Perhaps an Applescript I can add to my workflow that will remove that quarantine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Signature Check

Check your Automator application is being signed correctly. Do this using the command line tool `codesign`. Use the following command in **Terminal.app** to view the code signature associated with your application:

```
codesign -d -vvvv /Applications/MyGreatAutomator.app
```

Does the output mention your developer identifier? If not, revisit how you [sign your application](http://macosxautomation.com/mavericks/codesign/01.html) as it may be broken.

### Quarantine Flag

The quarantine flag is applied to files downloaded from the Internet. This flag can be manually removed using this command:

```
xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/MyGreatAutomator.app
```